# Issue in getting InputStream while using InMobi Ad SDK - Android

Tags: java, android, inputstream

In my android app I have used InMobi ad sdk to show banner ad's. After viewing the ad the following piece of code is not working.If not viewing the as the code works fine.Any one please help.

```
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection();
connection.connect();
InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
```

After viewing and closing the ad the above piece of code connection.getInputStream is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is that InMobi SDK overides the SetURL Redirect to false. I modified this to true and now works.

Answer (score 0):

please try following,

```
InputStream input = (InputStream)connection.getInputStream();

// operations 

input.close();
```

Comment: Thanks for ur answer but InputStream cannot be flushed.

Comment: opps I went to Java ME side, I have edited to code, please try it again

Comment: I want to close all unknown opened streams in the app.Seems the ad sdk getting hold of stream object and stream in my code getting corrupted. I want to free all the stream in the app.

Comment: then use static InputStream input .

Answer (score 0):

As per [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html)

```
InputStream input = (InputStream)connection.getInputStream();
input.close();
```

Here is note from HTTPURLConnection javadoc

Calling the close() methods on the InputStream or OutputStream of an HttpURLConnection after a request may free network resources associated with this instance but has no effect on any shared persistent connection. Calling the disconnect() method may close the underlying socket if a persistent connection is otherwise idle at that time.

Comment: I want to close all unknown opened streams in the app.Seems the ad sdk getting hold of stream object and stream in my code getting corrupted. I want to free all the stream in the app.

Comment: There is nothing like one shot for all. Every time you open a stream, in finally block you need to close the stream. That will take care of closing all streams intiated in that try/catch block.